# Driving Shaft Material

Tags: car, drive-shaft

What metal is a driving shaft made of.
I think it is a steel but breaking its components such as yoke, tube and others are they all made of same material?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question is too vague. Please use the [edit] feature and explain what vehicle you are working on and what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: This may be a question for engineering or chemistry but it would most likely be closed there...

Comment: They are commonly made of steel tube and cast iron ends welded on, this has changed recently to aluminum tubes and forged aluminum ends welded on, so mixed materials suited for their job.

Comment: I disagree that this question is vague, unclear or better suited for other stacks. OP is asking what the components are made of, and why they might break before the shaft itself does. That doesn't require an in-depth structural analysis to answer, and the question would likely be nuked on chem or engineering sites due to being 'trivial'.

Comment: @Moab - Write an answer with some good pics to show what you're talking about and I'll upvote you on it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You need to specify the make and model of vehicle you are talking about.  Some will be made from mild steel, some will be non-metallic composite materials.  It very much depends on the vehicle in question.  @Moab I don't think you can weld cast iron to steel.

Comment: @SteveMatthews It can be pretty rough depending on what you're welding, but you can weld cast iron to steel.  Cast iron is obviously softer and has a lower melting point.  So it's easy to burn through, but it can be done.